# Setting the background of a nav using toDataURL?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I've been working on a site that uses a JavaScript animation for the background of some of the sections.  Right now, the section in question is broken down like this:

```
    <section id="intro">
        <div class="info">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-full"><h1>My Name</h1></div>
                </div>
                <div class="row"><div class="col-1-4 centered line"></div></div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-full"><h4>Video<span class="cool">s</span> and stuff</h4></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <nav id="nav">
            <!-- The content between <span> </span> tags will be hidden on mobile version -->
            <ul class="clearfix">
                <li><a href="#profile">Pro<span>file</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#skills">Ski<span>lls</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#experience">Exp<span>erience</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#education">Edu<span>cation</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#portfolio">Por<span>tfolio</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Con<span>tact</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </section>
```

Originally, I wanted to set the background of the entire section using

```
    dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL();
    document.getElementById("intro")[0].style.background='url('+dataUrl+')'
```

but that didn't work, so I ended up going with

```
    dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL();
    document.getElementsByClassName("info")[0].style.background='url('+dataUrl+')'
```

which did.  However, the Nav bar scrolls with the page as you move down, and as soon as the script for scrolling it down kicks in, the background reverts to its default blue color.

My first thought was to simply add

```
document.getElementById("nav")[0].style.background='url('+dataUrl+')'
```

but that didn't work.  I had some success with

```
document.getElementByClassName("clearfix")[0].style.background='url('+dataUrl+')'
```

but only the area immediately surrounding the text used the animated background; the rest was still blue.

So I'm not sure if it's some issue with getElementById, or if you can't use style.background with `<section>` and `<nav>`.

Anyone have any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think you need the array selector with getElementById so try it on the whole section again and see if that will fix it for you.

So do `document.getElementById("intro").style.background='url('+dataUrl+')'`

Comment: Well I'll be darned... I still had to do a separate document.getElementById for the nav part, but it worked like a charm.  Thanks so much!